# JPA insert parent/child results in MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

This has already been asked a number of times, but I don't find any good answers so I'll ask it again.

I have parent-children unidirectional relation as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long parentId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "CHILD", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long parentId;

    //some other field
}
```

I create an instance of the parent, assign a list of children to it and try to persist it:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
Child c = new Child();
children.add(c);
p.addChildren(children);
em.merge(p);
```

When the code runs, I get the following exception:

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`testdb`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `parent_fk`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`) ON
>   DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that the parent is not fully inserted when the child is being attempted to be inserted.

If I don't add the children to the parent, the parent gets inserted just fine.
I tried switching the GeneratedValue generation strategy but that did not help.

Any ideas how to insert the parent & the children at the same time?

**Edit:** Even if I persist the parent first, I'm still getting the same error. I determined it's because the parent_id is not set in the child; the child is default constructed and thus the parent_id is set to 0 which does not exist thus the foreign key constraint validation.

Is there a way to get jpa to automatically set the parent_id of the children that are assigned to the parent instance?

Comment: If this supposed to be unidirectional relationship then why did you put `parentId` in `Child` entity ? Foreign keys are stored in the join table.

Comment: @ventsyv - has summed it up just right, that id is not needed at all in the child side.

Comment: @Biraj Choudhury I don't need it in the POJO, but I do need it in the table, so I assumed that JPA needs to "know" about it so it can set it to the correct value. If I remove it from the POJO, the query that's generated to insert the child is not setting the parent_id field, so that won't work.

Comment: You said you need a unidirectional relationship which mean you have three table parent(parent Id - PK , ChildId- FK, other fields), child (Child Id - PK), parent_child ( Child Id - Parent Id for the One to Many relation) . You will need the parent id in child only if you need a bi-directional relationship and which you can achive by @ManyToOne Parent parent;  Other than these two scenarios can you please tell what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Biraj Choudhury I have 2 tables - Parent & Child, where child has parent_id identifying the parent. It's one-to-many relation, one parent can have multiple children, but each child has only one parent. I want to archive (write to the DB) a list of parent objects, where each parent contains a list of children.

Comment: I wrote the code that can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your relationship does not have to be bi-directional. There is some mis-information in the comments here.

You also said that you had added the field "parentId" into the Child entity because you assumed that JPA needs to "know" about the parent field so that it can set the value. The problem is not that JPA does not know about the field, based on the annotations that you have provided. The problem is that you have provided "too much" information about the field, but that information is not internally consistent.

Change your field and annotation in Parent to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private List<Child> children;
```

Then remove the "parentId" from the Child entity entirely.
You had previously specified a JoinTable annotation. However, what you want is not a JoinTable. A JoinTable would create an additional third table in order to relate the two entities to each other. What you want is only a JoinColumn. Once you add the JoinColumn annotation onto a field that is also annotated with OneToMany, your JPA implementation will know that you are adding a FK into the CHILD table. The problem is that JPA has a CHILD table already defined with a column parent_id.

Think of it that you are giving it two conflicting definitions of both the function of the CHILD table and the parent_id column. In one case, you have told you JPA that it is an entity and the parent_id is simply a value in that entity. In the other, you have told JPA that your CHILD table is not an entity, but is used to create a foreign key relationship between your CHILD and PARENT table. The problem is that your CHILD table already exists. Then when you are persisting your entity, you have told it that the parent_id is explicitly null (not set) but then you have also told it that your parent_id should be updated to set a foreign key reference to the parent table.

I modified your code with the changes I described above, and I also called "persist" instead of "merge".

This resulted in 3 SQL queries

```
insert into PARENT (ID) values (default)
insert into CHILD (ID) values (default)
update CHILD set parent_id=? where ID=?
```

This reflects what you want perfectly. The PARENT entry is created. The CHILD entry is created, and then the CHILD record is updated to correctly set the foreign key.

If you instead add the annotation

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
private List<Child> children;
```

Then it will run the following query when it inserts the child

```
insert into CHILD (ID, parent_id) values (default, ?)
```

thus setting your FK propertly from the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I ended up doing. Great explanation. Is there a way to set the parent_id field in the child insert query, without having to run a separate update query?

Comment: I just updated my answer to modify the annotation to @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)

Comment: My JPA implementation still ran a second update query to set the FK again (not sure why) but I also see in my SQL log that the FK was set properly to begin with in the original insert

Comment: Same here, update query was ran even with nullable set to false which is very strange...

Comment: Perfect answer.  As it turns out, I was beating my head against the wall because I was missing the `nullable=false`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding updatable=false to the parent entity solved the problem with both an insert and an updated being executed on the child table. However, I have no clue why that's the case and in fact, I don't think what I am doing is correct because it means I cannot update the child table later on if I have to.

Answer (score 0):

I know persisting a new parent with children works for me using `em.persists(...)`.

Using `em.merge(...)`, really I don't know, but it sounds like it should work, but obviously you are running into troubles as your JPA implementation is trying to persists children before parent.

Maybe check if this works for you : https://vnageswararao.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/persist-entities-with-parent-child-relationship-using-jpa/

I don't know if this plays a role in your problem, but keep in mind that `em.merge(p);` will return a managed entity... and `p` will remain un-managed, and your children are linked to `p`.

A) try `em.persists(...)` rather than `em.merge(...)`

if you can't

B) you are merging `parent`... and you `cascade` is set to `CascadeType.PERSIST`. Try changing it to

- `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`
  or
- `cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}`

I know `merge` will persists newly created entities and should behave as `persists`, but these are my best hints.

Comment: See updated question, I think I determined that it's not the cascading that's to blame.

Comment: I tried all of those but nothing worked. I think the issue is that JPA is not able to figure out what parent id is when it's trying to insert the child object.

Answer (score 0):

What you wantto achieve you can achieve with this code.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PARENT")
    public class Parent {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long parentId;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        private List<Child> children;
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CHILD")
    public class Child {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        Parent parent;
    }
```

Comment: So it has to be bi-directional? Meaning that the Child POJO needs to have an instance of the Parent POJO? I was trying to not have the parent in the child POJO since it's not necessary (not going to be used).

Comment: That is what you want , to have the Parent Id in child

Comment: The table generated will only have the id, it wont have the other fields of the parent in Child.

Comment: I'm talking about the java object. The Child java object will have a reference to the Parent java object?

Comment: Yes it will.Why would you want it in the table ? if you didnt want it in the code ?

Comment: It could be in lazy load, so every time you load a child , parent is not loaded, but you can use it when you need it.

Comment: I'll never have to access the parent from the child that's why I don't want it in the child POJO.

Comment: So just remove the Parent parent, that will solve your peoblem

Comment: if I do that how am I going to set the foreign key in the child table?

Comment: OK, I've solved it. In addition to what you said, I had to remove the not null constraint on the parent_id key in the child table.This is due to the fact that JPA does the inserts first, then runs another query to update the parent id in the child table, but if the field is set to not null, you end up with the insert query throwing an exception. Add that to  your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: This annotation is incorrect. It will result in the creation of the following many-2-many (which a unique constraint, so it is a one-2-many table)
    create table PARENT_CHILD (
        PARENT_ID bigint not null,
        children_ID bigint not null,
        unique (children_ID)
    )
The correct annotation here is:
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "parent")