# Spring / JPA : saving entities having association entities

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities :  Product and Aisle. A product can be in one or many aisles and an aisle can have one or more products.
And an enity Salesman. A salesman is responsible for a product in an aisle:

```
@Entity 
public class Product{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle = new HashSet<>;
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}


@Entity 
public class Aisle{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String row;
   private String shelf;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aisle")
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle = new HashSet<>();
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}

@Entity 
public class ProductAisle{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Product product;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Aisle aisle;
   /* getters, setters, equals and hashcode */
}
@Entity 
public class Salesman{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Set<ProductAisle> productAisle;

}
```

For simplicity, I created a repository for each entity by extending the JpaRepositoryClass :

```
public interface SalesmanRepo extends JpaRepository<Salesman, Long>{}
public interface ProductAisleRepo extends JpaRepository<ProductAisle, Long>{}
public interface AisleRepo extends JpaRepository<Aisle, Long>{}
public interface ProductRepo extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{}
```

The problem is that I feel It's not the way to go.
For example, when I try to add a `Salesman`, I need to check if the `Product` exists. If not, I persist it through its repository.
Then I have to check if the `Aisle` exist. If not I persist it through its repository.
Next, I have to either find a record in the `ProductAisle` repository or create one.
Finally, I can save the `Salesman`.

**Question** : Is is the way to go to save entities joined with association entities ? Can I save the main entity (`Salesman`) without all the checks ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I may not have followed your question 100%; but it sounds like you're looking to have dependent entities created when inserting other entities?

In that case, you can try: cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST.  There's notes about it in a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786248/857994.

Also, here's a link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html that explains:

> PERSIST - If the parent entity is persisted into the persistence context, the related entity will also be persisted.

Comment: Yes for a whole new record. But if I want to reuse entities like `ProductAisle` (association table), am I obliged to try to get the items first, check if they are in the table. If not, insert them next ? I feel I'm doing things wrongly. One repository per entity ? Is it the way to go ?